# How to copy an Excel color scheme from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

Sometimes when I copy and paste from one workbook to another, the destination color scheme looks very odd. How can I copy the color scheme from one workbook to another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open VBA and type the following (changing the names of the workbook as appropriate)

```
workbooks("DestinationWorkbook.xlsx").Colors=workbooks("SourceWorkbook.xlsx").Colors
```